# django loaddata caused ProgrammingError: "..." is not a sequence when loading a long table name in postgresql

Tags: django

I'm loading a fixture generated from sqlite into postgresql database using manage.py loaddata. The loading failed when it reaches a ManyToManyField with a long name.

I traced into the database adapter: `usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py` line 44

`return self.cursor.execute(query, args)`

the value of `query` is correct: `'SELECT CURRVAL(\'"a_long_long_table_name_id_seq"\')'`

but then it failed with DatabaseError: "a_long_long_table_name_i" is not a sequence

Obviously the name is cut off after executing this statement, but I can't trace deeper.

django version: 1.2

How to fix this problem?

Comment: The maximum length of a column name in Postgres is 64 - both of your examples are much less than that. It's possible that the error message itself is simply truncating the column name. What happens when you run the query manually?

Comment: The 'a_long_long_table_name_' is not the actual table name which is much longer than this. So there is a hard limit in postgres that a table name should be less than 64 letters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer from http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-novice/2003-06/msg00239.php, postgres table name has a maximum limit of 63. To increase that limit, one has to change its source code and set `NAMEDATALEN` to higher value. But the problem is, in django, it's really easy to exceed this limit because the association table names for many-to-many fields usually are in this format: `application_name_model1_name_model2_name`

Anyway, I decided to shorten the model names and not re-compile the source code.

Answer (score 0):

You know that you can use app labels and db_table to specifically tell the database what name should be used as a table name, right? This means that you shouldn't need to shorten the names of Models, but keep them descriptive.

As far as I know, Postgres will truncate the name of a database table (and fields) on creation, using a function that will always yield the same name. This *should* mean that only the fixtures need to be modified. Determine the actual name within Postgres, and do a find replace on the fixture data.